# WCF, IIS6.0 (413) Request Entity Too Large

Tags: wcf, iis, https

guys. I've got annoyed problem. I've got WCF service(basicHttpBinding with Transport security Https). This service implements contract which consists 2 methods. LoadData. GetData. GetData works OK!. My client received pachage ~2Mb size without problems. All work correctly. But when I try load data by

```
  bool LoadData(Stream data); - signature of method
```

I'll get

```
 (413) Request Entity Too Large.
```

Stack Trace:

```
 Server stack trace: в 

ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateRequestReplyResponse(HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse response, HttpChannelFactory factory, WebException responseException, ChannelBinding channelBinding)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
```

I try this http://blogs.msdn.com/jiruss/archive/2007/04/13/http-413-request-entity-too-large-can-t-upload-large-files-using-iis6.aspx. 
But it doesn't work!
My server is 2003 with IIS6.0.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to make this change at the IIS level - may also need the WCF level changes above as well.

[MSDN blog: HTTP 413 request entity too large: can't upload large files using IIS6](http://blogs.msdn.com/jiruss/archive/2007/04/13/http-413-request-entity-too-large-can-t-upload-large-files-using-iis6.aspx)

Comment: Be attentive. I wrote "I try this http://blogs.msdn.com/jiruss/archive/2007/04/13/http-413-request-entity-too-large-can-t-upload-large-files-using-iis6.aspx"

Answer (score 0):

Check out the binding settings like `maxReceivedMessageSize` and the `readerQuotas` element has settings you should also probably be handling.

Comment: Note that for WCF REST endpoints the setting for maxReceivedMessageSize has to be set on the <standardEndpoint /> node.

Answer (score 0):

Million dollar point worth a note. maxReceivedMessageSize has to be set on  node. This stt worked like saviour to me. Thanks DreamTimeStudioZ a TON.