# WCF DataService or WCF endpoints for Batch Insert and Delete

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, wcf-data-services

We have a new client app that will be deployed on a remote server and interacting with our DB on another server via a WCF service of some type for various reasons. I am charged with building the DataLayer and Servicelayer.

Anyway, the issue is my comrade who is developing the MVC Client app is desiring to do Batch Inserts and Updates. Specifically building an entire object from the Parent down to all of it's children then committing this via the WCF in turn hitting the EntityModel and everything gets taken care of. However, I after creating a service layer with DTO's then using plain WCF endpoints, trying to to what he asks is a nightmare to deal with as the 413 error saying the size is too big is thrown no matter if I set the buffer size to max.

So then I tried WCF DataServices, and the more I play with it, I like it, however it seems like a Service Layer with DTO's is now not necessary and I cannot even figure out how to design one for it. And I do not believe it will do the type of Batch Transactions he is asking for, only separate objects, not nested. In addition, without a Service Layer, because of the way calls are made through the URI with ODATA, his repository pattern on his side will probably bloat. Also, am I not tightly coupling the Presentation(client) with my DataLayer?

What WCF type should I use and is his request even viable?

Answer (score 0):

The 413 error isn't coming from WCF, it's coming from IIS. So you should be able to take care of your main issue by following the advice in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2882011/wcf-iis6-0-413-request-entity-too-large) (unless your WCF message size is larger than 4GB, which would be another issue entirely).

Once you've restored sanity, you can come back to the question of whether WCF Data Services would make sense for your situation.

Comment: Thanks! I thought that was the answer. However, I cannot find anywhere in all my research that doing a cascade update through WCF will work.